# How to handle similar routes when one has integer parameter and other has string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am building a set of MVC pages pertaining to managing users, and I have the following routes defined in my `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Users", url: "Users", defaults: new { controller = "Users", action = "Index" });
routes.MapRoute(name: "User Details", url: "Users/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Users", action = "Edit",  id = UrlParameter.Optional });
routes.MapRoute(name: "User Creation", url: "Users/Create", defaults: new { controller = "Users", action = "Create" });
```

The problem I'm facing with this is that when I navigate to `/Users/Create`, the following error gets thrown:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int64)' in
>   'MyUI.Controllers.UsersController'. An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
>   parameter. Parameter name: parameters

It appears that it is unable to distinguish between a numerical ID being passed for `{id}` and `Create` being passed to help route to the right location.  This makes a bit of sense, since there's nowhere to hint the routing that `{id}` is a number, so how would it know?

My question ultimately breaks down to "How do you get the MVC routing to distinguish between these two cases, where a numeric id is passed in, in contrast to a string being passed in to call a different function in the controller?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a custom constraint to your route:

```
routes.MapRoute("users Route",
    "users/{Id}",
    new { controller = "Users", action= "GetUsers" },
    new { userId = @"\d+" }
);
```

This tells the routing engine that in order for the users route to be hit, there needs to be an all numerical route segment where the `{userId}` route segment is.

A Custom constraint can be just about anything that implements `IRouteConstraint`; in this case, I'm just using a regex to determine what the route constraint should be.

Answer (score 0):

MapRoute also takes a parameter for constraints, and for your "Users/{id}" you can specify a constraint that it has to be an integer (a regex \d+ should do probably).  Then it'll skip that route if URL is "/Users/Create" since "create" will fail constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You could just switch the order of route mappings -> "Users", "Users/Create", "Users/{id}".

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but doesn't the order play a role? What happens if you put "Users/Create" before "Users/{id}" in RouteConfig.cs?